# How to merge multiple php files into one php file

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to create a script that will get multiple PHP files and  make a one PHP file with that. E.g home.php, about.php, new.php Will be combined to form Index.php.

I've tried this code:

```
$code = '';
foreach (glob("*.php") as $filename) {
   $code.=file_get_contents("./$filename");
}
file_put_contents("./combined.php",$code);
```

but it won't output.

How could I merge multiple PHP files?

Comment: _“but it won't output”_ - meaning what, exactly? That it doesn’t create the desired file? Or that _that_ combined file then in turn does not show the expected output? // Your files would all have to “end” all their PHP blocks explicitly for this to work in the first place. If the `?>` at the very end of a file is left out (allowed in PHP, and actually recommended by most coding guidelines), then of course just concatenating the next block from the next file behind it, would only cause syntax errors.

Comment: @misorude Combined file doesn't show the expected output.

Comment: But - other, “unexpected” output? Or are we talking the classic “blank page”? The latter would mean, you should go enable proper PHP error reporting first of all.

Comment: @misorude Yes i am getting classic "blank page" not an unexpected error or syntox error.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your code on my machine and it seems it's working well. But can't understand why it's not working for you.

By the way, if you need more solutions, then you can also try the following ways.

If your files are coming from **form** then you can do it as follow:

```
$files = [];
$combine_files = $_POST['combine_files'];
foreach ($combine_files as $single_file)
{
    $files .= $single_file;
}

$combined_contents;
foreach ($files as $single_file)
{
    $combined_contents .= file_get_contents("./".$single_file);
}

file_put_contents("./combined.php",$combined_contents);
```

If not from **form**, then simply it can also be done by following way:

```
$files = ["home.php", "about.php", "new.php"]; // create an array of files
$combined_contents;
foreach ($files as $single_file)
{
    $combined_contents .= file_get_contents("./".$single_file);
}
file_put_contents("./combined.php",$combined_contents); // puts all contents into one file
```

Comment: @TowsifMy files are not coming from **form** file so I've tried this code:                             `$files = ["home.php", "about.php", "new.php"]; // create an array of files
$combined_contents;
foreach ($files as $single_file)
{
    $combined_contents .= file_get_contents("./".$single_file);
}
file_put_contents("./combined.php",$combined_contents); // puts all contents into one file`        but again it won't output.

Comment: I've tested it and it's working code. Are you trying on the same directory or different directory? or have you got any error?

Comment: I am trying on the same directory but getting "blank" page , not any error.